# MySQL Query based on PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is my Array:

```
array (size=2)
  100 => 
    array (size=2)
      'trade' => int 5
      'gold' => int 10
  101 => 
    array (size=2)
      'trade' => int 10
      'gold' => int 20
```

The key of the Array is the ID of the users which I want to run in a query. I figured out I probably need to use IN, example:

```
    SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (:id)
```

(:id is replaced by $id in the script)

Now when I do

```
     SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (100,105)
```

(for test purposes) it works.

Although it needs to be prepared so when I set

```
$id = 100,101;
```

or

```
$id = ‘100,101’;
```

it only displays the 100 record.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Unsure what you are asking. Are you asking how you would go about changing this to a prepared statement?

Comment: I am asking why it works when I put it directly into the query and not when assigned in a prepared statement - Thanks.

Comment: If you are passing the details through mysqli I think what has happened is that it has passed over that you want an id of "100, 101" rather than an id of 100 or an id of 101. Wouldn't expect that to work, but if it has I would assume that mysql has translated the string "100, 101" to an integer by dropping the first non numeric and anything after (ie the comma and 101), so matching against just 100. Passing variable length lists of items for a like is a pain as a parameter!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(",", array_keys($array)) . ")"
```

You can test this by using / specifying the array manually:

```
$array = array(
    100 => array(
        'trade' => 5,
        'gold' => 10,
    ),
    101 => array(
        'trade' => 10,
        'gold' => 20,
    )
);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(",", array_keys($array)) . ")";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

It's been actually tested and it works.

Comment: Great idea but this works like that, loading it directly into the query, but when I prepare it in a statement it just loads the first one in the list, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: foreach(implode(",", array_keys($array) as $value)
 - 
Try a foreach loop. Use $value in the bind.

Comment: Have you tried it yet? This should be the same as SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (100,105)

Comment: This doesn't work I get:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 

Don't know why though $array is defined: 

 $array = $_COOKIE['cart'];

Comment: Try to var_dump($array); and see what actually your $array is. Make sure that your $array does have keys like what you write on your question.

Comment: @SubRed It is really odd - var_dump shows that $array is exactly like the array on my first post, yet I get the foreach error

Answer (score 0):

they are both wrong what u have done `$id = 100,101;` and `$id = ‘100,101’;`
try this

```
  $id = "100,101";
```

or this

```
  $id = '100,101';
```

or even can do this also

```
    $id = 100;
    $id .= ",";
    $id .= 101 ;
```